# How to replace the single quotes on Word/notepad++

Tags: regex, ms-word, notepad++

I would like to replace the single quotes from the number in the below text.

```
('28','Harry Potter');
```

The output required is

```
(28,'Harry Potter');
```

What kind of regex is required to remove the quotes in Word/notepad++ ?

Comment: A bit off-topic, I think this probably belongs on superuser.

Comment: I looking to do this in word or notepad++.

Comment: That does not make it more on-topic. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what is on topic.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will delete this question..

Comment: @MikkelBueTellus: Why do you thing It is off topic? it's a question about regex in notepad++ that is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Toto The question doesn't seem to be about software development, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @MikkelBueTellus: So we should close all questions about Npp (3650 at his time) and regex (137841) ?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `'(\d+)'`
Replace with: `$1`

Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will remove all single quotes arround digits.

Answer (score 0):

For Word 2010:

Use
Find what:

```
([0-9]{2,})
```

replace with:

```
\1
```

[image]

Comment: Play with this regex. If your number is single digit or more use {1,} instead

Comment: In the replacement part use $1 instead of \1 that represents a back reference, not a group. Even if it works in Npp for legacy reason.

Comment: Welcome to world of word. In ms word \1 is used for replacement. This is not Javascript regex. This is ms word wild card. And it works

Comment: @Toto: for notepad++ also I am successfully using \1 for replacements.

Comment: Yes it works, but for legacy reason. `\1` should be used only within the regex, not in the replacement part.